# Python nested dictionary add key:values from json

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

This is my first question on StackOverflow.
I searched throughly as always (that's why it's my first question ever !) but can't seem to get my head around what seems to be a simple problem...

**What I'm doing:**

- I'm getting answers from a cryptocurrency API as a json
- I filter this json to get only the elements I want
- I then add, for each market, the "from/to: price" key:value pair to a dictionary

**My problem** :

I would like to build a dictionary like so :

{Market:{FROM/TO: price, FROM/TO: price, ...}, {Market:{FROM/TO: price, FROM/TO: price, ...}, ...}

to use it as a dataframe afterwards.

But what I get from my actual code is a dictionary like that :

{Market:{FROM/TO: price}, {Market:{FROM/TO: price}}

Where 'FROM/TO: price' is the last 'Key:value' sent by the API (in my example code, it's ETH/USD, when it exists for a market).

I would like my code to "see" where a "Market" key already exists in the dictionary, and to append all new "FROM/TO: price" pairs to this "Market" key.

I know that something's wrong with my code (obviously), but I really can't get my head around it...

**My actual code**:

```
import requests
import json

d = {}
s = []
def get_data_from_url(*args):
"""
Get datas from an API url.
Treat it as json and filter everything not needed.
"""
for symbol_pair in args:
    for symbols in symbol_pair:
        from_symbol, to_symbol = symbols
        url = 'https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshot/?fsym=' \
            + from_symbol + '&tsym=' + to_symbol
        resp = requests.get(url=url)
        datas = json.loads(resp.text)

        # filter to get only the exchanges data
        exchanges_data = datas["Data"]["Exchanges"]

        for data_dict in exchanges_data:
            if data_dict["TOSYMBOL"] == "WUSD":
                data_dict["TOSYMBOL"] = "USD"
            # if the exchange is not outdated
            if data_dict["VOLUME24HOUR"] != "0":
                # s.append([data_dict["MARKET"], {data_dict["FROMSYMBOL"] + "/" + data_dict["TOSYMBOL"]: data_dict["PRICE"]}])
                d[data_dict["MARKET"]] = {}

                d[data_dict["MARKET"]].update({data_dict["FROMSYMBOL"] + "/" + data_dict["TOSYMBOL"]: data_dict["PRICE"]})
print(d)

args = [("BTC", "USD"), ("ETH", "USD")]

get_data_from_url(args)
```

Could you please help me solve this problem ?
I would be really grateful !

Thanks everyone and keep it nice Pythonistas :)

Comment: Can you please format your data sample as it would appear in a properly formatted document?

Comment: Please post a MCVE without any dep on external resources (the `datas` should be hardcoded in the example) and with the example outputs expected from the given `datas`.

Comment: Hi ! I'm sorry about that, next time I will post an MCVE without external dependencies.
@v100ev got me on the good tracks, his solution works and I knew it was something that "easy".
Thanks guys for your early replies :)

PS : I'll edit my code to post datas not depending on external sources, if anyone needs it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got your problem. It's pretty simple - You were creating a dict and updating it each time. You should check if it exists first and then update. And if it doesn't exist - create it with it's first element. Something like this (it works):

```
            # if the exchange is not outdated
            if data_dict["VOLUME24HOUR"] != "0":
                if d.get(data_dict["MARKET"]):
                    d[data_dict["MARKET"]].update({data_dict["FROMSYMBOL"] + "/" + data_dict["TOSYMBOL"]: data_dict["PRICE"]})
                else:
                    d[data_dict["MARKET"]]= {data_dict["FROMSYMBOL"] + "/" + data_dict["TOSYMBOL"]: data_dict["PRICE"]}
```

Comment: Thanks @v100ev, your answer works, and I knew it was not that hard !
You saved me from a lot more headhaches. :)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you update `d[data_dict["MARKET"]]`, you first set it to `{}`. So of course it only contains the last piece of data; all the others were deleted when the next piece of data came along. You should look for an existing dictionary and take an empty dictionary as default only if it doesn't already exist. For example:

```
 d[data_dict["MARKET"]] = d.get([data_dict["MARKET"],{}).update({data_dict["FROMSYMBOL"] + "/" + data_dict["TOSYMBOL"]: data_dict["PRICE"]})
```